# React FullCalendar console error changedOptionNames is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am trying to use fullCalendar on my react project and I followed the steps that I saw on their docs, all plugins library that I am using, I install and imported but when I try to use `eventsSet` and change the State function I got a console error.

If I comment the `eventsSet` the Calendar works, does someone know what could be causing this?

my code:
https://github.com/wandersonce/Admin-Dashboard/blob/main/src/scenes/calendar/index.jsx

```
<pre>
import { useState } from 'react';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import { formatDate } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import {
  Box,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemText,
  Typography,
  useTheme,
} from '@mui/material';
import Header from '../../components/Header';
import { tokens } from '../../theme';

export default function Calendar() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  const [currentEvents, setCurrentEvents] = useState([]);

  const handleDateClick = (selected) => {
    const title = prompt('Please enter a new title for your event');
    const calendarApi = selected.view.calendar;
    calendarApi.unselect();

    if (title) {
      calendarApi.addEvent({
        id: `${selected.dateStr}-${title}`,
        title,
        start: selected.startStr,
        end: selected.endStr,
        allDay: selected.allDay,
      });
    }
  };

  const handleEventClick = (selected) => {
    if (
      window.confirm(
        `Are you sure you want to delete the event '${selected.event.title}'`
      )
    ) {
      selected.event.remove();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box m="20px">
      <Header title="Calendar" subtitle="Full Calendar Interactive Page" />

      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
        {/* CALENDAR SIDEBAR */}
        <Box
          flex="1 1 20%"
          backgroundColor={colors.primary[400]}
          p="15px"
          borderRadius="4px"
        >
          <Typography variant="h5">Events</Typography>
          <List>
            {currentEvents.map((event) => (
              <ListItem
                key={event.id}
                sx={{
                  backgroundColor: colors.greenAccent[500],
                  margin: '10px 0',
                  borderRadius: '2px',
                }}
              >
                <ListItemText
                  primary={event.title}
                  secondary={
                    <Typography>
                      {formatDate(event.start, {
                        year: 'numeric',
                        month: 'short',
                        day: 'numeric',
                      })}
                    </Typography>
                  }
                />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
        </Box>

        {/* CALENDAR */}
        <Box flex="1 1 100%" ml="15px">
          <FullCalendar
            height="75vh"
            plugins={[
              dayGridPlugin,
              timeGridPlugin,
              interactionPlugin,
              listPlugin,
            ]}
            headerToolbar={{
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth',
            }}
            initialView="dayGridMonth"
            editable={true}
            selectable={true}
            selectMirror={true}
            dayMaxEvents={true}
            select={handleDateClick}
            eventClick={handleEventClick}
            initialEvents={[
              {
                id: '12315',
                title: 'All-day event',
                date: '2022-09-14',
              },
              {
                id: '5123',
                title: 'Timed event',
                date: '2022-09-28',
              },
            ]}
            eventsSet={(events) => setCurrentEvents(events)}
          />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );

</pre>
```

and the error:
[image: Error in the console]

Comment: did you find out what was wrong?

Comment: It turned out the versions in my package.json for calendar didn't match, I had @fullcalendar/vue3 with 6.0.3 and @fullcalendar/rrule 6.1.1. Once I fixed this everything started working again

Comment: I will try see if the version is the problem